# How to export to csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the code below that I would like to have exported to a csv file. Not sure where I would put the export-csv line?

```
Get-ChildItem \\server\share| Where {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | Get-ACL | ForEach {
    $Identity = $_.Access | Where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*-W'}
    $Group = ($Identity.IdentityReference -split '\\')[1]
    If ($Identity) {
        "Found $($Identity.IdentityReference)"
        #Assumes you do not have ActiveDirectory module
        $Members = ([adsisearcher]"name=$($Group)").FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().member -replace 'CN=(.*?)\,.*','$1'
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FullName = Convert-Path $_.Path
            Identity = $Identity.IdentityReference
            Members = $Members

        }

    }

}
```

This is the current output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all of the new objects as an array. This is done by pipelining the result of your command. So you need to place `Export-CSV` at the end...

```
Get-ChildItem \\server\share| Where {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | Get-ACL | ForEach {
    $Identity = $_.Access | Where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*-W'}
    $Group = ($Identity.IdentityReference -split '\\')[1]
    If ($Identity) {
        "Found $($Identity.IdentityReference)"
        #Assumes you do not have ActiveDirectory module
        $Members = ([adsisearcher]"name=$($Group)").FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().member -replace 'CN=(.*?)\,.*','$1'
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FullName = Convert-Path $_.Path
            Identity = $Identity.IdentityReference
            Members = $Members

        }

    }

} | Export-CSV c:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: when I do this it is not exporting the data? Just says #TYPE System.String length

Comment: If you run the script without `export-csv`, how is your data presented? can you include a real(but sanitised) sample in your question?

Comment: Sure, I added an image above

Comment: I still stand by my answer. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @user1342164: Show the output that `Export-Csv` creates.